# Every time prompt about svn password

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

Linux Mint 20.3

Eclipse 2022

When I start IntelIJ IDEA 2022 it ask me about svn password. I input my credential and check on "Save password". After restart IntelIJ IDEA NOT ask me anymore about svn password.

But when I start Eclipse 2022 it's ask me EVERY time about svn password. Check on "Save password" NOT help.

[image]

Here my SVN settings:

[image]

[image]

Install two plugins:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which SVN plug-in is this?

Comment: @nitind I was updated my post

Answer (score 2):

Subclipse does not cache credentials. It relies upon the SVN API provider to do so via API callbacks. Native SVN on Linux will not cache credentials in recent SVN versions because it is only capable of caching them in plain text and so this was removed. If you can use gnome-keyring then it would cache.

IntelliJ does not use native SVN. It uses the SVNKit library which can just do whatever it chooses. It could be SVNKit caches the credentials or more likely IntelliJ just has its own cache.

You can try configuring Subclipse on Eclipse to use SVNKit as the API provider. This *might* cache credentials but that is up to SVNKit and not Subclipse.